# Looping through array and searching a database for a match

Tags: mysql, arrays, loops

Everyday I receive a csv file with phone numbers.  I've built an array that grabs the data from the csv.  What I need to do is loop through the array and search a mysql database for matches. Can one of your gurus be so kind as to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to create temporary table, then load your numbers into this table and then just simply select & join to your table. You can insert your phones in program (multilple rows in one `INSERT` or if you has access to server shell, you can do some script like this:

```
-- you can use TEMPORARY table in one transaction or you can just
-- make sure that the table exists and flush it before import

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS phonenumbers (
    number varchar(10) primary key
);

TRUNCATE TABLE phonenumbers;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'numbers.csv' INTO TABLE phonenumbers;

-- here in script or call it from your program to work with data
-- also you can add  INTO OUTFILE 'output.csv' to export filtered data
-- into outfile 

SELECT addressbook.* FROM addressbook LEFT JOIN phonenumbers on (addressbook.phone = phonenumbers.number);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to, import the csv into a temporary table using [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) and write a query that matches the table against your phone numbers.

Comment: It's a better process all around as this only requires database interaction. You do not have to worry about arrays or loops.